# NetDiag + TCP Blocking?

Tags: networking, sharepoint, tcpip, windows

We are facing some issue with the sharepoint 2007 timer jobs everyday at a specific time, so decide to track the tcp blocking informartion during those hours using NetDiag tool. We are not able to find the required information if we uses "netdiag /test:ipsec", what is the command that can be used to pull the TCP blocking information and how to configure it?

if i ran the command "netdiag /test:ipsec /debug" it is returning "IP Security test . . . . . . . . . : Skipped", what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

run "netsh ipsec dynamic show /?" for more detailed information

Checks whether IPsec is enabled and if so then lists all active IPsec policies for the computer